# Supremum not in subset

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $s=\sup A$. What I need to prove is that if $s\notin A$ then for every $\epsilon >0$ the interval $(s-\epsilon , s)$ contains infinitely many elements of $A$.

I need a hint/guidance regarding the last statement. How does one exhibit that a subset contains infinitely many elements of $A$? Do I need to show that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? Do I show that there doesn't exists an isomorphism with a finite set?

Comment: Suppose otherwise.  Then there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that ..........    And then what does this imply about the supremum of $A$?  Could it still have been $s$?  Or is there a smaller candidate?  Why?

Comment: A finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a maximal element.

Answer (score 1):

One way that works here is just to show you can keep picking a new one.  Let $a_0 \in A$ with $s-\epsilon \lt a_0$.  How do you know it exists?  We know $a_0 \lt s$ is not an upper bound, so there must be an element $a_1$ with $a_1 \gt a_0$ that is in $A$.  But $a_1 \lt s$ as well...

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = \sup(A) \not\in A$.  Fix some $\varepsilon > 0$.  By definition of the supremum, there is some $a_1 \in A$ such that
$$ s-\varepsilon < a_1 < s. $$
We can now choose infinitely many elements of $A$ between $s-\varepsilon$ and $s$ by induction:  suppose that $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{n} \subseteq A$ have been chosen so that $s- \varepsilon <a_j < s_{a+1} < s$ for all $j = 1, \dots, n-1$.  Then set $\varepsilon_n := s - a_n > 0$.  By definition of the supremum, there is some $a_{n+1} \in (s-\varepsilon, s) = (a_n, s)$.  But then $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq A \cap (s-\varepsilon, s)$ is an infinite collection, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since supremum of a set is the least upper bound of that set any number which is strictly less than the supremum is not an upper bound. In your problem $s-\epsilon$ is less than $s$ therefore the set has a member x1 in $(s-\epsilon,s)$. Now this new element is strictly less than $s$ so there is an element x2  in $(x1,s)$. Similarly we can find $x3<x4<x5<..$ in $(s-\epsilon.,s)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Set $s=\sup A$.

The OP might want to prove the following first:

Proposition: If $s\notin A$, then for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $A \cap (r,+\infty)$ is either empty or infinite. It is empty $\text{iff } r \ge s$.